# Flakehell ignores additional setup.cfg parameter for darglint

Tags: python, flake8

I'm using [Flakehell](https://github.com/life4/flakehell) to lint my python project.
I installed and activated [darglint](https://github.com/terrencepreilly/darglint) for flakehell.
Then I want to set my docstring style to *numpy*.
First, I added `docstring_style = "numpy"` to `tool.flakehell` section in my *pyproject.toml*.
Additionally, I set `docstring_style = numpy` in *setup.cfg* (used by darglint).
When running `darglint` in terminal everything works fine, but using flakehell it does not detect my additional setting and gives me linting errors containing wrong docstrings...

My *pyproject.toml*:

```
[tool.flakehell]
docstring_style = "numpy"

[tool.flakehell.plugins]
flake8-darglint = ["+*"]
```

*setup.cfg*:

```
[darglint]
docstring_style = numpy
```

Why does flakehell ignores darglint setting?
How to set this option via flakehell?
Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

according to [the `darglint` documentation](https://github.com/terrencepreilly/darglint#configuration) you'd specify the darglint settings in their configuration section:

```
[darglint]
docstring_style = numpy
```

Comment: yep, tried this as well (see above). Strange thing is, that after some time - flakehell seemed to accept the settings. As far as I know, I didn't change anything - but now it works?! Does Flakehell has some caching inside? Only checks files after file changes or something?? I will observe it and post comment, if I know whats going on. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: I'm just the flake8 maintainer, flakehell appears to be a big hack on top of flake8 so I wouldn't be surprised if it's buggy